# SASpy file_delete Method

Tags: python-3.x, sas, saspy

Does anyone has used the file_delete() method of SASpy? I'm trying to delete a file in SAS Server side using this method but I was unable to make it works.

```
sas.file_delete(filepath='/au/gac/public/data', fileref='myfile', quiet = False)
```

I got: AttributeError: 'SASsession' object has no attribute 'file_delete'

Comment: Question: what version of SASPy are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this.  In 3.3.7 this is not available; in 3.6.6 it is available.  I'm not sure exactly what version it was added in (most likely 3.5.0, that seemed to be a big update), but most likely you just need to run:

```
pip install saspy --upgrade
```

(While SASPY is not open) and it will work.

---

Separately, now that we have the right version, I think you may be misunderstanding the arguments to file_delete.

`filepath` should not just be the folder path - it should include the filename.  I don't know exactly how AIX handles these things, but the `fileref` is *not* to tell SAS what file you want - it's actually just used in `filename [fileref] [filepath];` in the actual SAS code.  I'm not really sure why you'd even want this, except perhaps to later do something with that fileref.

Make sure your `filepath` includes the entire directory tree plus the filename of what you want to delete.

Comment: I was using version 3.3.6

Comment: Did work now, but I got The "filepath provided does not exist". I'm pretty sure the path is correct.

Comment: Hmm, worked fine for me... `rc = sas.file_delete("h:/temp/test.txt")`  Are you confident SAS can see the file?  Maybe consider passing the delete as SAS code - to see if it's possible - and if that fails then you know it's not SASPy but it's something with SAS's inability to see it.

Comment: Here we have a SAS server running in AIX and, Yes, I can delete the file if do sas.saslib(libref="mylib", path="/au/ga/data")  and then sas.submit('proc delete data=mylib.file; run;')

Comment: Using sas.file_delete() I got that The "filepath provided does not exist" message mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm, try looking at the log?   `print(rc['LOG'])` if you ran `rc = sas.file_delete...`.  That is where the message comes from (there is a return from there) but it will also show what SAS saw when you passed it that.

Comment: Oh, now I think I see the issue; will edit the answer.

Comment: I will give a try tomorrow, and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hi Joe! I tried today using your tip, and it works. So, as you said, the filepath must include the file name, e.g. sas.file_delete(filepath='/au/gac/public/data/myfile.sas7bdat', quiet = True). Thanks for your help.